# Identifying Marin Factors In Ansys For Fatigue Analysis

Tags: stresses, machine-design, ansys, ansys-workbench, fatigue

I am conducting a fatigue analysis for a mechanical shaft on ANSYS. Everything is fine except for defining marin factors. I am eager to specify some crucial marin factors, such as the temperature factor, which, in my case, will significantly reduce the endurance strength due to the high-temperature application. I have been trying and searching extensively but haven't figured out how to identify these factors in ANSYS to obtain comprehensive results from my fatigue analysis.

Comment: Isn't the point of using ANSYS in not wanting to use (at least some Marin) factors? ANSYS (or other FEAs) can calculate stress in time which allows you to use fatigue calculation principles more directly. Temperature factor might be tricky, because ANSYS cannot account for changes in material endurance limit due to temperature (you would need to specify these), but it allows you to simulate additional thermal stresses if there are any.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations for specifying these?

Comment: Unfortunately not, but temperature influence will depend on material composition. You can try to look up some material and fatigue calculation standards. You could also specify the material in the question.